receiving duplicate message with socket IO in flutter
I use this package in my flutter app, I faced a problem. Sometimes when user is sending message through socket, they received duplicate messages; actually socket.on('EVENT', (data){}) is performed 2 times. after restarting app, this bug fixed.
How can I fixed it? is it a server side bug or client side?
How can I get more information about this?
Thanks

I think this is a server-side error. You can tell the server to check the log

there's no log there. he said I sent just one time.

Make sure your are listen to your socketIO just once in your code.
Also you can check this with the backend developer who make socketIO connection.
Otherwise, to prevent the duplication in firing events, you can check the previous value if it equals the new event just ignore it else fire a new event.

Well you maybe using cubit with io socket
so you are displaying chat list but before it maybe like this
Expanded(
  child: BlocBuilder<MessageCubit, List<Message>>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state.isNotEmpty) {

So, here you are adding everytime all list of messages not the last one so here the state contain all the list
So when you need to add try like this:
messages.add(state.last);


no. I used GetX in project.

same idea you are sending the whole list of message every time

just last message is duplicated; not entire list
